# batch editing - unwanted requests or payload

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

For last 4 days I'm pulling my hair because of this issue I'm having.
If I try to update multiple items inside store at once I get weird payload.
What do I mean by weird:
first request has data for first item,
second for first and second,
third for first, second and third and so on.

If I turn off batchActions I get 55 requests for 10 items in my store.
**When I'm editing 30 items I'm getting 465 requests!**

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="extjs/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //MODEL
        Ext.define('Test.model.Shift', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty: 'id',
            fields: [{
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'StartDate',
                type: 'date',
                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
            }, {
                name: 'EndDate',
                type: 'date',
                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
            }, {
                name: 'Cls',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'Draggable',
                type: 'bool',
                defaultValue: true
            }, {
                name: 'Resizable',
                type: 'bool',
                defaultValue: true
            }]
        });


         //STORE
        Ext.define('Test.store.Shifts', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'Test.model.Shift',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: true,//I need this!!!
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                //batchActions: true,
                pageParam: false,
                startParam: false,
                limitParam: false,
                noCache: false,
                url: 'json.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                update: function (store, record, operation, eOpts) {
                    switch (operation) {
                    case Ext.data.Model.EDIT:
                        console.log('INFO', 'Updating record...');
                        break;
                    case Ext.data.Model.COMMIT:
                        console.log('INFO', 'Record was updated!');
                        break;
                    case Ext.data.Model.REJECT:
                        console.log('ERR', 'Something went horribly wrong :( Data was rejected!');
                        break;
                    }
                },
                beforesync: function (options, eOpts) {
                    console.log(options);
                }
            }
        });


         //SCHEDULER
        Ext.define("Test.view.Scheduler", {
            extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
            alias: 'widget.my_scheduler',
            title: 'Scheduler',
            region: 'center',
            split: true,
            initComponent: function () {
                var me = this;
                me.store = Ext.create("Test.store.Shifts");


                Ext.apply(me, {
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'Id',
                        dataIndex: 'id',
                        hideable: false,
                        width: 260,
                        sortable: true,
                        resizable: false
                    }, {
                        text: 'Cls',
                        dataIndex: 'Cls',
                        hideable: false,
                        flex: 1,
                        sortable: true,
                        resizable: false
                    }],
                    dockedItems: [{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Update',
                            listeners: {
                                click: function () {
                                    var mixed = me.store.queryBy(function (rec) {
                                        if (rec.data.Cls === 'cls') return true;
                                    });
                                    Ext.each(mixed.getRange(), function (rec, index) {
                                        rec.set('Cls', 'cls2');
                                    }, this);
                                },
                                scope: this
                            }
                        }]
                    }],
                });
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });


         //APP
        Ext.application({
            name: "Test",
            launch: function () {
                this.setupLayout();
            },
            setupLayout: function () {
                Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
                    layout: 'border',
                    margins: 5,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        region: 'north',
                        html: 'test'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'my_scheduler'
                    }]
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

any json.php

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');


$list = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $list[] = array('id' => $i, 'UserId' => $i, 'StartDate' => '2013-01-06', 'EndDate' => '2013-01-08', 'Cls' => 'cls', 'Draggable' =>true, Resizable =>true);
}
$data = array('success'=>true, data=>$list);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

200 OK is proper header for PUT operation in REST service so server can't be the issue.
I can remove batchActions, but this way I'll have unwanted requests, if I set batchActions I'll get unwanted payload.

Any advice on this one?

Here's my test page: Here is my test page: http://tomasz.jagusz.pl/masterthesis/test/

**EDIT:**
To test other PUT response I've edited original example that comes with ExtJS 4.2.1 - `restfull` example.
I've added below code to toolbar:

```
{
    itemId: 'updateAll',
    text: 'Update All',
    handler: function(){
        Ext.each(grid.store.getRange(), function (rec, index) {
            rec.set('last', 'Test');
        }, this);
    }
}
```

This allows me to update all records at once.

For request like this:

```
{"id":1,"email":"fred@flintstone.com","first":"Fred","last":"Test"}
```

Server is responding with:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Updated User 1","data":{"id":1,"first":"Fred","last":"Test","email":"fred@flintstone.com"}}
```

This should be fine, but for 6 records I get 21 requests!

Here is my another test: http://tomasz.jagusz.pl/masterthesis/test2/restful.html

**EDIT 2**

Here is version that is working for me now:

```
{
    itemId: 'updateAll',
    text: 'Update All',
    handler: function(){
        grid.store.suspendAutoSync();
        Ext.each(grid.store.getRange(), function (rec, index) {
            rec.set('last', 'Test'+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)  );
        }, this);
        grid.store.resumeAutoSync();
        grid.store.sync();
    }
}
```

I'm stopping autosync, then I'm doing changes locally, resuming autosync and finally syncing all changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ExtJS updates data:

1. It sends the request with the json data
2. It parses the response.

   - If the record was updated correctly, it discards the update operation from the queue.
   - If the record failed to update, it keeps the update operation in the queue and resends it the next time.

The reason why you get every request resent is that the response you get from the server is not correct. When updating `Cls` from `cls` to `cls2`, you send this to the server:

```
{"id":7,"StartDate":"2013-01-06","EndDate":"2013-01-08","Cls":"cls2","Draggable":true,"Resizable":true}
```

The server should respond with

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"id":7,"StartDate":"2013-01-06","EndDate":"2013-01-08","Cls":"cls2","Draggable":true,"Resizable":true}]}
```

But in your case it returns all lines without the update, that is incorrectly with `"Cls":"cls"`. This tells ExtJS, that the update was not successful, even though you send `success: true`. That's why ExtJS will resend the update operation on each `store.sync()`

Comment: I've testes same code, but my backend was returning status 200 OK, which is correct PUT response (RFC2616). So even when me server was returning no content and that header I still was getting those requests. I'll modify my code to see if that changes something. But I think `200 OK` (without data) should be fine. Imagine I'm updating 300 items in store at once. Thats a lot of data to send, but also to receive (when server needs to return data)

Comment: Look, status code alone is not sufficient. ExtJs expects a `success` parameter and the NEW content of the updated record.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I past I was updating items one at a time and everything was working nice, but I must say that I wasn't counting requests. I'll modify my test code right away :)

Comment: Please see my updated question. I've edited restful example that comes with ExtJS 4.2.1 I get same results.

Comment: Manual updates work now for me. Only your button `Update all` is sending multiple requests. I think the problem lies in the code of that button. Recommendation: Change the values of the lines only locally, then `.sync()` your store only once.

Comment: Manual updates are fine, but I have problem with batch. Can I disable autosync, then update all records locally and turn on autosync? Will this sync all changes? If Yes then could You please help me with building code?

Comment: I've edited my question again with solution that works :) Would it be possible to not send data in response? Or am I asking too much? :)

Comment: I don't know for sure, you have to try. But afaik, ExtJS expects the data in the response.

Comment: Just tested that, seems everything is working fine :) But I guess that returning data is fine, especially if server is modifying some of fields.